# how to return value from a if block in scala

Tags: scala

I want to return an integer type from an if block like in this sample code:

```
def a {
  val res = if (1 == 1) {
    val x = 1
    b(x)
  }
}

def b(x:Int) = {
  20
}
```

Here the type of res is  `val res: AnyVal`

How can I change it to `Int`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have a default value to return, then you could return an `Option[Int]` instead, and combine this with `getOrElse`:

```
def a(n: Int): Option[Int] = {
  if (n < 100) {
    Some(n * 2)
  } else {
    None
  }
}

a(10).getOrElse("Something else")
```

---

Another possibility is to use **partial functions**, because in your case your first function does not cover all cases, and you want to have a fallback:

```
val a: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case n if n < 100 =>
    n * 2
}

val b: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case _ =>
    "Something else"
}
```

Then you can use `applyOrElse`:

```
// If function a is not defined for the input, then call function b
val result = a.applyOrElse(10, b)
```

or combine both partial functions into another function, and call that one:

```
// Combine a and b
val cf = a.orElse(b)
// Call
val result = cf(10)
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to add `else` alternative, for example:

```
  def a {
    val res = if (1 == 1) {
      val x = 1
      b(x)
    } else 0
  }
```

This happens because for absent `else` case compiler uses `Unit`. And nearest common type for `Int` and `Unit` is `AnyVal`.

Comment: in my case there is no default value :(

Comment: What are you going to return in case when your `if` condition is `false`? Will be it always `true`?

Comment: when if fails i want to call another function that return type string

Comment: Then result type will be `Any`. You can't evaluate your expression to `Int` if any of its branches are not of type `Int`.

Comment: Or its subclass (for example `Nothing`, if you throw an exception at invalid branch) .

Answer (score 0):

The reason you didn't get a determined int is that: your if block miss some code path. So if you change to:

```
val res = if (i == 1) {
    val x = 1
    b(x)
} else {
    0 // some default value
}
```

That will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To have an immutable value `val res` well-defined with an `if-else` expression, both parts of the expression need be declared, as aforementioned. Even in the case of a mutable variable

```
var res: Int = _
```

the compiler instantiates it to a default `0`. Thereafter it is valid for instance to

```
if (1 == 1) res = 20
```

without having to define the `else` part.